# my divs won't align correctly. why?

Tags: css, html, alignment, multiple-columns

This webpage looks fine in dreamweaver but when I view it in any browser, 3 columns are not inside wrapper2 id.  It doesn't even show up. I can't figure out why.

This is my HTML code

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="menu"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper2">
            <div id="leftpane"></div>
            <div id="bodycontent"></div>
            <div id="rightpane"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

here is css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#wrapper #header #menu {
    background-color: #00F;
    height: 50px;
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
#wrapper #header {
    background-image: url(../images/index_03.gif);
    height: 200px;
    width: 900px;
}
#wrapper2 {
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    background-color:#999;
    height:auto;
}
#leftpane {
    width:200px;
    height:347px;
    background-color:#C96;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
#rightpane {
    width:200px;
    height:347px;
    background-color:#C96;
    margin:5px;
    float:right;

}
#bodycontent {
    width:400px;
    margin:5px;
    height:347px;
    background-color:#C96;
    float:left;
}
#footer {
    width:900px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#0C6;
}
```

Please can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you please setup a demo @ http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mayRY/ - Unless I'm missing something, it actually looks ok.

Comment: @PeeHaa I [have added it](http://jsfiddle.net/E7yBJ/1/) - the problem looks like `height: auto;` that won't work with floating elements - see in my example I set it to fixed height and it looks fine..

Comment: hi guys, sorry for my late reply. but i don't want to specify a fixed height because i want it to expand as content grows. how ever Andres Ilich answer works. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it you're not clearing your floated `#wrapper2` elements. Try clearing the wrapper like so:

```
#wrapper2:before, #wrapper2:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    zoom:1; /* ie fix */
}

#wrapper2:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @guitarlass great, if the answer cleared your question please consider accepting it as such by using the checkmark besides the answer. That way it can help future users with the same problem.

Comment: @guitarlass its [this one](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png) right here, from the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @guitarlarlass: if this works for you then you should accept this answer and upvote it (i give +1)